# Call to action button within/out of a table on a pricing page

Tags: tables, placement, pricing, cta

I am wondering if there are any points/reasons regarding UX in defense of either one of those two solutions: the CTA outside of the table at all or in the bottom "section". 
Not minding the colors that would be used, however I feel like that makes some difference once I start to color it.

I would appreciate any help in that dilemma.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I personally wouldn't mind either of the two. Offer 1 might take preference if there's plenty of distracting content around, on the page, bringing the risk of "losing the button out of sight".

Answer (score 2):

> The key to effectively chunking content (text as well as images, graphics, videos, buttons, and other elements) is to keep related things close together and aligned (in accordance with the **Law of Proximity** in Gestalt psychology). -[nngroup](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/chunking/)

-

> **The Isolation Effect** (also known as the Von Restorff Effect) is the tendency to recall something that stands out in a group and afford it more weighting than its peers. -[Psychology in Design (Part 1)](https://blog.prototypr.io/psychology-in-design-part-1-cdc63229cbe4)

So together, You need to have the button inside the container and it needs to stand out in order to catch the eye of your users.

---

Some relevant examples are attached:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple—it's Gestalt psychology, we tend to perceive items boxed together to belong to each other. By including the button in the box, you make it a bit more associated with the content of the box.

I'd go with proposal 1, as it carries across the association better.